# Transforming flat to table to hierarchical list in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class called Item

```
class Item
    {
        // these are fields in the database
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        public readonly List<int> AncestorIds = new List<int>();

        public List<Item> Children;
    }
```

A list of said Items

```
static readonly List<Item> Items = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item {Id = 1, ParentId = null},
        new Item {Id = 2, ParentId = null},
        new Item {Id = 3, ParentId = null},
        new Item {Id = 4, ParentId = 1},
        new Item {Id = 5, ParentId = 1},
        new Item {Id = 6, ParentId = 1},
        new Item {Id = 7, ParentId = 2},
        new Item {Id = 8, ParentId = 2},
        new Item {Id = 9, ParentId = 3},
        new Item {Id = 10, ParentId = 4},
        new Item {Id = 11, ParentId = 4},
        new Item {Id = 12, ParentId = 5},
        new Item {Id = 13, ParentId = 7},
        new Item {Id = 14, ParentId = 8},
        new Item {Id = 99, ParentId = 14},
        new Item {Id = 100, ParentId = 99},
        new Item {Id = 101, ParentId = 99},
        new Item {Id = 102, ParentId = 99},
        new Item {Id = 103, ParentId = 100},
        new Item {Id = 104, ParentId = 100},
        new Item {Id = 105, ParentId = 100},
        new Item {Id = 106, ParentId = 103},
        new Item {Id = 107, ParentId = 103},
    };
```

What I'm trying to do is populate all of the children of children of children. Basically turning the flat list of items into a hierarchical list/tree. Here are the two methods of been using to test out my work

```
static void PopulateChildren(List<Item> children)
    {
        if (children == null || children.Count == 0)
            return;

        var lookup = Items.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);
        foreach (var item in children)
        {
            item.Children = lookup[item.Id].ToList();

        }
    }

    static void PrintChildIds(Item item, string prefix = "")
    {
        if (item.Children == null || item.Children.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{prefix}Item {item.Id} has no children!");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{prefix}Item {item.Id} has children: ");
        prefix += "-";
        foreach (var child in item.Children)
        {
            PrintChildIds(child, prefix);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not getting the right output as expected however. I'm not sure if it's because I need to use recursion or what but any help at all would be appreciated.

EDIT:
This is my main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = Items;
        var item = items.First(x => x.Id == 99);

        item.Children = items.Where(x => x.ParentId == 99).ToList();

        PopulateAncestorIds(item);
        Console.WriteLine($"Found parent IDs: {string.Join(",", item.AncestorIds)}");

        PopulateChildren(item.Children);
        PrintChildIds(item); 

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but it seems like you're never assigning `Children`, so your `PopulateChildren()` method would immediately return. You don't need to keep track of children if you combine parentID with linq. `var childNodes = Items.where(i => i.parentID == someNode.ID);`

Comment: What exactly not working for you? `PopulateChildren(Items); PrintChildIds(Items.First());` at first glance seems to be working fine.

Comment: @GuruStron it only goes down one level to find the children. For example, take 99 for instance. The three children of 99 are (100,101,102). Item 101 and 102 have no children and the output is fine for that, but for item 100 there are three children (103,104, 105). After it finds those three children it should check those children again to see if they have any. In this instance 103, has two so it should print those out as well, but currently it outputs 103 has no children.

Comment: @wishywashy and please how you are using all this code.

Answer (score 0):

Without example usage I would say that you are using `PopulateChildren` with some arbitrary list of items, if it is so then you need to populate children for your `Items` list first:

```
PopulateChildren(Items);
```

After that it has all levels populated and prints everything correctly:

```
PrintChildIds(Items.First(i => i.Id == 99));
```

Gives:

```
Item 99 has children: 
-Item 100 has children: 
--Item 103 has children: 
---Item 106 has no children!
---Item 107 has no children!
--Item 104 has no children!
--Item 105 has no children!
-Item 101 has no children!
-Item 102 has no children!
```

And this works also:

```
var newList = new List<Item> { new Item {Id = 99}}; 
PopulateChildren(newList);
PrintChildIds(newList.First());
```

Giving the same output.

**UPD**

This works fine for me (`PopulateAncestorIds` commented out cause was not provided):

```
var items = Items;
var item = items.First(x => x.Id == 99);

item.Children = items.Where(x => x.ParentId == 99).ToList();

// PopulateAncestorIds(item);
// Console.WriteLine($"Found parent IDs: {string.Join(",", item.AncestorIds)}");

PopulateChildren(Items); // populate your Items as I suggested
PopulateChildren(item.Children);
PrintChildIds(item);

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
```

Comment: Just edited the post to include my main method. I don't think I'm using an arbitrary list of items based on my main. I could be wrong though

Comment: @wishywashy the same applies to your code - call `PopulateChildren(Items);` before ` PopulateChildren(item.Children);`

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong then because when I call PopulateChildren(Items) I get a stack overflow

Comment: @wishywashy where do you place `PopulateChildren(Items)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Thank you all to tried to help answer the question. Turns out all i needed to do was add a recursive call in my PopulateChildren method.

Original:

```
static void PopulateChildren(List<Item> children)
    {
        if (children == null || children.Count == 0)
            return;

        var lookup = Items.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);
        foreach (var item in children)
        {
            item.Children = lookup[item.Id].ToList();   
        }
    }
```

Correct:

```
static void PopulateChildren(List<Item> children)
    {
        if (children == null || children.Count == 0)
            return;

        var lookup = Items.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);
        foreach (var item in children)
        {
            item.Children = lookup[item.Id].ToList();
            PopulateChildren(item.Children);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hello sir if you have code for this PopulateAncestorIds  method please i need